# Font file issue using Dompdf in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using the Dompdf package in Laravel to download pdf's.  I have the following in my web.php:

```
Route::get('proposal-pdf/{id}', function($id) {
$proposal = Proposal::find($id);

// $pdf = PDF::loadView('test', compact('proposal'));
$pdf = PDF::loadView('internal-admin-tools.proposal-pdf', compact('proposal'));
return $pdf->download('proposal.pdf');

return back();
```

});

I downloaded Dompdf using: composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf.

I have a view using fonts that come with Laravel.  I get the following error:

fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\HealthHub\storage\fonts/\176125b1b6dc4704cbf0390040859779.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I added the 'fonts' directory in my 'storage' and then added the file named above.  After I do that and reload, the load does not render.  I think I may have to change the permissions to my 'fonts' folder and cannot find any clear answer here on how to do that.  I have not done that before.  I am using VSCode and XAMPP. I navigated to the 'fonts' folder in the terminal and entered:  chmod mode 777.  It says 'chmod' isn't recognized

Comment: navigate to the storage and use "cacls myfile.txt /g everyone:f" to change the permission, because you are in windows, so chmod doesn't work

Comment: thanks, i was able to do that, but still not able to load the pdf.  I think that package is not compatible with Laravel's out of the box fonts

Comment: use google fonts...

Answer (score 0):

Creating `storage\fonts` directory should fix the problem.